# Cannot find module 'tailwind-config/tailwind.config.js' even though the tailwind.config.js file exists (Novel Editor)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, yarnpkg, wysiwyg

I cloned the Novel repo (https://github.com/steven-tey/novel) and proceded to build the NextJS web app that was included in the `novel/apps/web` folder using Yarn. I ran `yarn` at the top level folder to install dependencies and `yarn dev` in the `apps/web` folder to build the app. The app crashes when loaded on the browser and produces the following error:

```
./styles/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[12].use[3]!./styles/globals.css
Error: Cannot find module 'tailwind-config/tailwind.config.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/levita/novel/apps/web/tailwind.config.js
```

However, the file `tailwind.config.js` exists in the `novel/apps/web` folder where I am running the `yarn dev` command.

I tried initializing Tailwind by running `npx tailwindcss init` per the [Tailwind installation instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation). However, I got the following message:

```
tailwind.config.js already exists.
```

So it seems like the config file is in the correct location, but if so, why would the app crash and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `tailwind.config.js` file that is included with the project requires a second "shared config" file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const sharedConfig = require("tailwind-config/tailwind.config.js");

module.exports = {
  presets: [sharedConfig],
};
```

This second config file, however, does not exist in `apps/web/node_modules/tailwind-config`. Hence the missing module.

How to fix it? I am still learning Tailwind and web dev in general, so although what I did got the app to load, it may cause issues down the road. I assumed that the example config (shown in the [installation page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)) would have good default values, so I replaced the original `tailwind.config.js` with the example `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The result is that the app no longer searches for the shared config and the web app loads.